# Deriving the PDF of an exponentially modified Gaussian RV

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, density-function, exponential-distribution

For a random variable $Z = X + Y$, where $X$ is an exponential RV with $λ = 1$ and $Y$ is a Gaussian (Normal) random variable with mean $μ$ and standard deviation $σ$, how could we derive the distribution of $Z$? The Wikipedia page for the exponentially modified Gaussian (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentially_modified_Gaussian_distribution) states that the PDF is given by the relationship shown below but I can't seem to find how it is derived.

[image: Eponentially modified Gaussian PDF]

I know that for a sum of two random variables, the distribution can be found by taking the following convolution: $$f_{Z}(z)=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }f_{X}(z-y)f_{Y}(y)$$  But I cannot figure out how to apply it to the case above with a Gaussian RV and a exponential RV.

Comment: The Wikipedia article references this PDF and the reference is available online.  On its first page it shows you the substitution you can use to convert the convolution into this expression: see https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ac60319a011 and formulas (1) and (2) and the following text.